# Wii U USB Memory Stick Photo Slideshow

Tags: wii-u

Is there anyway to play a slideshow of photos saved on a USB stick on the Wii U? If not, can it be done with an SD card? I remember being able to look at photos on the original Wii, but cannot find out how to on the Wii U.

Comment: There's a Wii mode; have you tried that?

Comment: Yep, but I couldn't figure out how to access USB for storage, just SD.

Comment: I don't believe even the Wii itself allowed USB storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible in WiiU-mode (nor Wii-mode) as it lacks a photo/media viewer.

Comment: There is no photo channel on Wii menu in the Wii U.